# wp contact form 7 save form to database & mail also

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add a wp7 contact form in wordpress site but I want it to mail as well as save form filled data in database table as well. Is there any way I can make it happen.

Comment: The way you've asked this question, it is off-topic.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask If you ask this question with some code examples, someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple plugins that are doing saving in the database. You can find them [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/cf7+db/).

If you want to save in custom database or table you can use action 'wpcf7_mail_sent' to get values and everything then to process to destination.